# Use plyr to summarize a data.frame and get counts of each unique item

Tags: r, grouping, plyr, run-length-encoding

I have a data.frame with task assignments from a ticket tracking system.

```
Assignments <- data.frame('Task'=c(1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1), 'Assignee'=c('Alice', 'Bob', 'Alice', 'Alice', 'Bob', 'Chuck', 'Alice'))
```

I need to summarize the data for some monthly reports. Here is what I have so far:

```
ddply(Assignments, 'Task', 
      summarize, 
      Assignee.Count=length(Assignee), 
      Unique.Assignees.Involved=length(unique(Assignee)),
      Assignees.Involved=paste(Assignee, sep=", ", collapse=", "))
```

And that nets me:

```
  Task Assignee.Count Unique.Assignees.Involved Assignees.Involved
1    1              3                         2  Alice, Bob, Alice
2    2              3                         3  Alice, Bob, Chuck
3    3              1                         1              Alice
```

In the Assignees.Involved column, I'd like to further summarize the data. In line 1, I'd like it to say "Alice 2, Bob 1".  It feels to me like I need to use some other `plyr` method to take the Assignees for each task, sort them, then run them through the `rle` function, and paste the lengths and values back together. I can't figure out how to do that within the summarize function.

Here is the result for the whole entire data.frame:

```
paste(rle(as.vector(sort(Assignments$Assignee)))$values,
      rle(as.vector(sort(Assignments$Assignee)))$lengths,
      sep=" ", collapse=", ")
```

Results:

```
[1] "Alice 4, Bob 2, Chuck 1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out while posting the question :)

The trick is that within the functions specified as arguments to the `summarize` function, you refer to them as a bareword; `Assignments$Assignee` should be called just `Assignee`, no data frame, no quotes, etc.

So once I had figured out that the `rle` function could get me where I needed to be, I had what I needed.

```
ddply(Assignments, 'Task', 
      summarize, 
      Assignee.Count=length(Assignee), 
      Unique.Assignees.Involved=length(unique(Assignee)), 
      Assignments=paste(rle(as.vector(sort(Assignee)))$values, 
                        rle(as.vector(sort(Assignee)))$lengths, 
                        sep=" ", collapse=", "))
```

Gives:

```
  Task Assignee.Count Unique.Assignees.Involved             Assignments
1    1              3                         2          Alice 2, Bob 1
2    2              3                         3 Alice 1, Bob 1, Chuck 1
3    3              1                         1                 Alice 1
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, and rle() complains that 'x' must be an atomic vector. My version.string is R version 3.0.0 (2013-04-03)

Comment: Sorry, yes, I am required by law to forget that I run R with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` at least once a week. If that column were a character vector, rather than a factor, you wouldn't need the `as.vector`.

Comment: I am new to R and get tripped up by that all the time. It doesn't help that in my data sets (mostly IT security metrics) sometimes I want strings as factors and sometimes as strings.